# NameError: name 'app' is not defined In Python

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and i have been struggling to create an sqlite database but whenever i run the `from app import db` I get the error message:

> NameError: name 'app' is not defined

This is my code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db.init_app(app)


class Todo:
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(length=300), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task %r>' % self.id


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

The image below is my directory structure. I don't know if it has anything to do with it: [Image of directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfBsQ.png)

I tried `import db from app` so that I will create the db file.

Comment: Please post the full error message. The script you posted, what is its name? Are you running this script and getting the error or are you running some other script?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Are you sure this is the actual code you are running? Are there other modules (python files) you haven't mentioned?

Comment: I am using to the command line to create the db for this particular project and there are no other modules.

Answer (score -1):

First u need to replace `db.init_app(app)` with `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`. The starting code could look like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Then after your class Todo:

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```